Using v-center and m keys for \Block creates additional vertical space space


The exact height of the space is 2.25pt
When setting a weight for the second column, the issue disappears
For p column type the issue disappears, but if its width increases, it appears again
This seems to be an issue only with NiceTabularX

My MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{} X[l, t] X[l, t]@{}}[rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines]
    
    Text 1 \newline Text 2 \newline Text 3 \newline Text 4
    & \Block[l,v-center]{1-1}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
    \\
    
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{1-1}{\rbrace}
    
\end{NiceTabularX}

\bigskip

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}p[l]{1cm} l@{}}[rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines]
    
    Text 1 \newline Text 2 \newline Text 3 \newline Text 4
    & \Block[l,v-center]{1-1}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
    \\
    
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{1-1}{\rbrace}
    
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


You should consider accepting the answer, otherwise, the question will com black in a few months...

@F.Pantigny. Definitely

I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of nicematrix (6.28b of 2024/06/29) which solves that bug.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} X[l, t] X[l, t]@{}}[rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines]
    Text 1 \newline Text 2 \newline Text 3 \newline Text 4
    & \Block[l,v-center]{1-1}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
    \\
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{1-1}{\rbrace}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


